# How to install drivers from the "tar.gz" package?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04

Many times I tried to install the `tar.gz` driver packages based on various tips from our beloved community, but unfortunately I have failed this art so far.

---

Could I ask for full, detailed and accurate installation instructions? It can be an example *[ToolKit](https://github.com/nefarius/ScpToolkit/releases/tag/v1.7.277.16103-BETA)*

Comment: That's a .NET project and I think you have to install [.NET core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu) to be able to build it.And after that you have to run ```dotnet build``` to compile the project.

Comment: The example you give, ToolKit, clearly says that it is a Windows driver in the README: "Windows Driver and XInput Wrapper for Sony DualShock 3/4 Controllers" I am unaware of any method whatever to compile this driver for Ubuntu 20.04 or, for that matter, any version of Linux. Sorry.

Comment: Yo
(https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/PCE-AC55BT/DR_PCE_AC55BT_22.1.7.0.zip)  
I wanted to install drivers from the manufacturer's official website, I don't know how it happened, but they are in ZIP. When I unpack, I have _iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0.tgz_, which I can't deal with yet.
If that's not a problem, please guide me.

Comment: The link you provided in the question is different from the one posted in the comments.```iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0.tgz``` only contains some microcodes which are used to initialize the device.It's not a driver.Which driver do you want to install ? iwlwifi? If so, that driver is preinstalled in linux.You just have to run ```sudo modprobe iwlwifi``` to be able to use it.

Comment: Ok THX
Do I need to find the folder location from the terminal level, open / enter it and enter the specified command?

Comment: You can run that command from anywhere you want.In fact the drivers are located in ```/lib/modules/kernel_version/kernel/drivers/```.But the ```modprobe``` command fetches the drivers from there automatically.There's no need to change the directory to that.

Comment: I did something wrong again:

dandar3nascie @ laborat13: ~ $ cd /home/dandar3nascie/Dan/Instalki/WiFi/iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0/
dandar3nascie @ laborat13: ~ / Dan / Instalki / WiFi / iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0 $ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
[sudo] password for the user dandar3nascie:
dandar3nascie @ laborat13: ~ / Dan / Instalki / WiFi / iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0 $ sudo modprobe iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic
dandar3nascie laborat13 @: ~ / Dan / instalki / WiFi / iwlwifi-7260-ucode-$ 22.1.7.0

Comment: I think ```sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms``` can solve the problem.But in my system that driver is pre-installed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Parsa Mousavi, it started

Comment: Module has been obsoleted due to being included
in kernel 5.4.0.  We will avoid installing
for future kernels above 5.4.0.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod.........

DKMS: install completed.
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu man-db (2.9.1-1)...
Error: Timeout was reached
dandar3nascie@laborat13:~/Dan/Instalki/WiFi/iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0$

Comment: ... ok, I don't quite understand and how to do it, but the most important thing is that the card works as it should. I am asking for further tips if possible

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the driver `iwlwifi` you have to install the package `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`.

Comment: @DanDar3nascie You're welcome.And if it's helpful please consider accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was:

```
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Of course, I unpacked the ZIP achive first.

And after the problem and it's all thanks to the wonderful Ubuntu community. Thank you, you are great!
And especially @Parsa Mousavi

Comment: As this post currently stands, it is more likely a "Thank You" post. Instead of posting "Thank You", you can accept the answer which helped as already [stated by Parsa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256053/how-to-install-drivers-from-the-tar-gz-package#comment2122321_1256077).